# Is it possible to disable opening on key enter for select 2 (v 4.0.3)

Tags: jquery-select2

Is it possible to disable opening on key enter for select 2 (v 4.0.3). I found somewhere that it can be done with options "openOnEnter: false", but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. At the time of version 4.0.3 at least.
It's hardcoded:

```
this.on('keypress', function (evt) {
  var key = evt.which;

  if (self.isOpen()) {
    // skipped
  } else {
    if (key === KEYS.ENTER || key === KEYS.SPACE ||
        (key === KEYS.DOWN && evt.altKey)) {
      self.open();

      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour to open the dropdown on Enter key press is hardcoded (as @Shrike said) and there is no option available to disable it (`openOnEnter` was used in v3, but was removed in v4).

I've found the following (*dirty*) solution, for **Select2 v4** and **single select**, :

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.select2-selection', function (evt) {
    if (evt.which === 13) {
        $("#mySelect").select2('close');
    }
});
```

I catch the `keydown` event and call the select2 `close` method to immediately close the dropdown.

Tested in Chrome, Mozzila, Safari.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9t6sv8d/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using select2.full.min.js, you may search for "a.open" and replace that part of the code with the one below:

```
this.options.get("disabled") ? b.preventDefault() : a.open()
```

This will inspect if the select2 element is disabled and prevent any further action.